# How to properly register genericAPI view in Django and solve 405 error

Tags: django

I have a view looking like below

```
class UserFpProfileView(generics.GenericAPIView,
                              mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                              mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):
    serializer_class = UserFpProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    # authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            **request.data
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def get_object(self):
        # Raise error if user type is not fp
        if self.request.user.type != 'fp':
            raise exceptions.PermissionDenied(detail='FP 계정만 접근할 수 있습니다.')

        queryset = self.queryset
        queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

        return queryset
```

and route looking like below

```
path('me/fp-profile/', views.UserFpProfileView.as_view(), name='fp-profile'),
```

When I post or get to 'me/fp-profile' URL I get 405 method not allowed error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: the methdo `get_object()` should return a ***model instance***, not a QuerySet

Comment: maybe try `http_method_names=['post']`

Comment: @Sahil where do I put that?

Comment: Below `permission_classes` should work.

Comment: Is your request url correct? Can you check it?